# Is Java 7 already available to develop?

Tags: java

Is Java 7 already available to do development with?

Comment: ok, I accepted the others now. I didnt know how to do it =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start developing with Java 7 already, just go [here](https://jdk7.dev.java.net/).

Please note though that you will be using snapshot builds/sources so there are probably bugs and some unfinished/changing API.

Comment: thank you, but what's the difference between snapshot and beta?

Comment: A beta is notionally feature-complete.  A snapshot may or may not be  notionally feature-complete.